# jquery resizable to show left-right panel splitter not working as expected when content includes vertical scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am implementing jquery resizable to show two horizontal panels (leftpanel & rightpanel) with a drag-bar between the two. I have added a border-right to include a black line on the right of the left_pane to assist in locating where to drag).

This works when there is little content, but when content is added (using the [Add Content] button):

1. The split-dragging stops working/is no longer draggable (is this because of the vertical scrollbar?)
2. The split-dragger position is to the left of the scrollbar rather than the expected "black line" position.

[image]

```js
$("#left_pane").resizable({
  handles: 'e',
  resize: function() {
    $("#right_pane").outerWidth($("#container").innerWidth() - $("#left_pane").outerWidth());
  }
});


function addContent() {
  // Fill out the pane content...
  var lp = document.getElementById('left_pane');
  var rp = document.getElementById('right_pane');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    lp.innerHTML += lp.innerText + ' ';
    rp.innerHTML += rp.innerText + ' ';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

#left_pane,
#right_pane {
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  overflow:auto;
}

#left_pane {
  width: 25%;
  left: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

#right_pane {
  width: 75%;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
}

button {
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<button onClick='addContent()'>Add Content</button>

<div id="container">Container
  <div id="left_pane">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
  <div id="right_pane">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

A running example can be also found on https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/xvhc615j/9/

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function addContent(event) {
    var panes = $("div[id*='PaneContent']");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {;
      panes.append(" " + panes.eq(0).text());
    }
  }

  $("#addContent").click(addContent);

  $("#leftPaneWrapper").resizable({
    handles: {
      e: "#leftPaneHandle"
    },
    resize: function(e, ui) {
      $("#rightPaneContent").width($("#container").width() - ui.size.width);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

div[id*='PaneContent'] {
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

#leftPaneWrapper {
  width: 25%;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#leftPaneHandle {
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 3px;
}

#leftPaneContent {
  background: lightgrey;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  padding-right: 0;
}

#rightPaneContent {
  width: 75%;
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
  background: white;
}

button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="addContent">Add Content</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftPaneWrapper">
    <div id="leftPaneHandle" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div id="leftPaneContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightPaneContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
</div>
```

You can use Custom Handles. When you add a Border to an element, it is not the Handle for Resizable.

> The following keys are supported: `{ n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw }`. The value of any specified should be a jQuery selector matching the child element of the resizable to use as that handle. If the handle is not a child of the resizable, you can pass in the DOMElement or a valid jQuery object directly.

> Note: When generating your own handles, each handle must have the `ui-resizable-handle` class, as well as the appropriate `ui-resizable-{direction}` class, .e.g., `ui-resizable-s`

See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

I created a Wrapper for the left panel, inside it, I added a Handle and the content. When more content is added, the overflow kicks in for just the content, and does not effect the handle or the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks - that worked, although I did need to include margins and padding on the resize too (`resize: function(e, ui) {
                      $("#rightPaneContent").width($("#container").width() - ui.size.width  - parseInt($("#rightPaneContent").css("margin-left")) - parseInt($("#rightPaneContent").css("margin-right")) - parseInt($("#rightPaneContent").css("padding-left")) - parseInt($("#rightPaneContent").css("padding-right")));`